# Huawei ec156 Tata Photon+ not working in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: mobile-broadband

My Tata Photon device will shows up in the terminal when I ran the command `lsusb`. However, it doesn't show on the desktop.

It also doesn't work as a flash drive.

Comment: Take a look at [Ubuntu - Install Tata Photon +](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/209-ubuntu-tata-photonplus) which has the installation instructions for Huwei EC156 provided with a Tata Photon + subscription.